# Why does the file size increase after I clipped the polygons to be smaller?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kml

I have a polygon layer that shows properties along a road.

I want to create a kml-file of the polygons, and to downsize the file, I tried clipping the properties with a buffer. But, the filesize of the shapefile increased from 370 kB to 1.97 MB, and when I saved the clipped file to kml it ended up being almost 5 MB?

Why does the filesize increase and what can I do differently to get a smaller kml-file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of a polygon on disk does not depend on its extent but on the number of vertices. If you want to reduce the size, you can use some generalization tools (e.g. simplify geometries). Also make sure that you do not create extra small polygons when clipping.

Comment: Simplify geometries did the trick! I got the file down to 90 kB (shp), it worked really well on some of my lines as well.